# How do I get the guids of taxonomy/metadata terms for updating lists?

Tags: sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2010

I'm integrating a legacy system with SP2010 using a literal SOAP calls. I can do a call such as CopyIntoItems or UpdateListItems and doing so, set metadata fields by providing a Fields node such as:

```
  <Fields>
       <FieldInformation Type="Note" DisplayName="Country_0"
                         Id="de1e6424-7a8a-42a5-8d21-73402fe2e609"
                         Value="UK|91c89925-16e6-4d41-9e71-ec45e8f2a113" />
       ...
  </Fields>
```

In the Value attribute, I have to give the guid of the taxonomy or metadata term. That works fine in the above example since I happen to know the guid of the term UK. However, how can I dynamically figure out what the guid of some other value, say France for example, would be? I was thinking of making a utility to get them all and cache them on my system somehow so I can look them up easily, but where are they defined?

Possibly a stupid question, I get the feeling I've missed something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MSDN Sharepoint 2010 forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepoint2010general/thread/63553372-b87f-4d69-8d4c-63fb8a7b3c6d

Not sure if this is the best way but it's the answer I'm going with for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

The [GetList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlist%28v=office.12%29.aspx) call should allow you to get all the ID's.

But the [UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289%28v=office.12%29.aspx) ([and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)) call should work using just the internal names.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately UpdateListItems refuses to do anything without the GUID of the value - returns success but ignores the update. Also I can't get Lists.GetList to return any taxonomy fields - what would the ListName parameter be?